# How to add points in degrees + decimal minutes to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geocaching

I try to add geocaches with x,y coordinates in a xls-table to qgis and convert to shp.file.

Usally geocach-coordinates are like this: N 51° 29.440' E 011° 56.430' (WGS84) (in german its called "bogenminute) . But it seems that qgis only know geographic coordinate system (WGS 84) with coordinates like this one: 51.754683 12.000967 ("dezimalgrad"). So i can charge them from one to another but i think its sensless. There must be a easier way.

Is there another geographic coordinate system ,qgis has,  to add the points directly from the first format (bogenminute)?

Comment: Are your coordinates in two columns - one for latitude one for longitude?

Answer (score 5):

You could use regular expressions in the field calculator (QGIS 1.9 / 2.0, *not* 1.8!) to extract the appropriate numbers and do some basic arithmetic. If your latitude is in the 'lat' column:

```
regexp_substr("lat", '(\\d+)') + (regexp_substr("lat", '(\\d+).(\\d+)') / 60)
```

From your example - N 51° 29.440' – this gives 51.4906667.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, QGIS' **Add Delimited Text Layer** plugin can only import coordinates in **decimal degrees** (51.754683 12.000967) format and not in the **degrees, minutes, seconds** (N 51° 29.440' E 011° 56.430') format.

Comment: ok thank you for helping.
is there another way/plugin who can import in format deegrees, minutes, seconds?

Comment: Not in Qgis, but in Excel: http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic512318_0_0_asc.php. You can import the result into Qgis.

Comment: as Andre Joost already told you, you can easliy convert to decimal degrees in your spreadsheet (Excel, OO, Libreoffice,...): Decimal lat/lon = degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600

Comment: ADDENDUM:Keep in mind that South latitude and West longitude are negative

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 2.8 it is possible to load it with **Add Delimited Text Layer** and check the **DMS Coordinates** checkbox next to the X field and Y field combo boxes.